# Scanning and making into a .jpg

Tags: scanning

How do scan a document to make it into a .jpg. I have an epson cx3650 and open office but this only saves in .odg which is not recognised in such things a facebook and other programmes.

Comment: Try File>Export that allows all sorts of different formats

Answer (score 3):

well you can do that with an application named as `xsane`. To install that open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install xsane
```

Then open that from unity dash. there you can do.

one more thing is after you save the images in your default format of scanner , you can re-save them into desired format by using Gimp which is also can be installable from your terminal with

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Also imagemagick can convert from pnm created by xsane to jpg: convert file.pnm file.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'convert' as part of 'imagemagick'

```
convert file.odg file.jpg
```

See [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) for more details.

**UPDATE:** Actually imagemagick fails for me, so I would recommend opening the image in OpenOffice Draw, then exporting as a PDF. Then use imagemagick to convert from PDF to JPG.

```
convert file.pdf file.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the **`.odg`** file in **Open Office** and then click **`File`**->**`Export`**.

- On the **`Export`** dialog box that opens, provide your desired filename,
- then find the "Save as type:" selection,
- Select the file type: **`JPEG (.jpg ...)`**, and then click **`Save`**.
- On the small dialoge box that opens, specify your desired quality setting (100 is "best").
- Click **`OK`** to complete the **`Export`** operation.

The original **`.odg`** file will still be open in **Open Office**. You can close **Open Office**, and then view/edit/use your newly created **`.jpg`** file in other programs and applications, and on web sites like Facebook.

Depending on the content that is being scanned (photo, drawing, text, etc...), it might be a better choice to save the file in another standard format like **`.png`**. The process would be similar to exporting to **`.jpg`** (**`.png`** will have a "Compression" setting [0=none/minimum to 9=maximum compression] instead of a "Quality" setting).

Answer (score 0):

there is one more application named as simplescan. you can install it from terminal with

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:robert-ancell/simple-scan
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install simple-scan
```